# Post body is optional field in questions method?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

```
"body": {
    "description": "body of this post",
    "values": "string",
    "optional": true
},
```

Post **body** is optional field in [questions](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions) method? Shouldn't all the posts have body field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `body` to false in the request, `body` on all the responses (two different fields of two different types in two different contexts with the same name... makes it hard to discuss...) is not set.

Basically, `body` is an optionally returned field.

Comment: Ah, you're right, forgot about the parameter :D